# Why my webpage is displayed with question marks, if i switch encoding to UTF-8?

Tags: asp.net, encoding, web, globalization

Within the web.config file i have the following, regarding encoding info, since the website is availiale only to Greece.

```
<globalization fileEncoding="windows-1253" requestEncoding="windows-1253" responseEncoding="windows-1253" culture="el-gr" uiCulture="el"/>
```

What changes should i implement if i decide to add the English version of the website too?

**UPDATE:**

1) The hosting server is not located in Greece.

2) Only the dynamically created text is displayed correctly. All other text is displayed as question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf-8 should be sufficient shouldnt it?

Comment: Check what the page is encoded as.  Visual Studio -> File -> Advanced Save Options (underneath save), it allows you to specify the file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You have also to check the page culture specification.